# WordPress and bbPress Login conflicts?

Tags: wp-admin, login, bbpress

For some reason, if I log into my WordPress dashboard, I get logged out of my bbPress forum. When I log into my bbPress forum, I get logged out of WordPress.

I followed all of the instructions correctly, and the installation told me it validated my information and it's all correct, so why is it not letting me stay logged into both at the same time?

Comment: Have you checked whether they are overwriting each others cookies? The cookie name is suffixed with the `COOKIEHASH`, which, if you don't set it in `wp-config.php`, is the MD5 of the `siteurl`.

Comment: @Jan Fabry: I haven't, honestly I'm not sure how to check if they are overwriting each others cookies. Care to explain?

Comment: You can use this with the developer tools of your browser. For Firefox you need to install [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/), for other browsers it's included (usually called "Developer toolbar"). Log in to WordPress and search for a `wordpress_logged_in_XXX` cookie. The `XXX` is the cookie hash. If you log in to bbPress you should get a second cookie, it should not overwrite the existing one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve so by following this tutorial - http://blog.ashfame.com/2009/07/integrate-bbpress-10-with-wordpress-28/ and then keeping the bbPress integration plugin active on WordPress side (it is responsible for generating bbPress admin side cookies when you login from WordPress).
So see where you missed out and get it back on track. Let me know if you are stuck or lost.